# how to migrate data to update form ASP classic

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

i have ASP page that contains clickable table with student information and when i click ID for student take me to update form filled with his information

how could i get these information  in the update form ?

Comment: You need use javascript to make this element editable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the information is not sensitive, you could pass the value of the fields in the URL which then populates the fields in your update form.
If you add the code you are working with, then I'll be happy to give you a specific example.